# Understanding [&] in C++ lambda capture specification

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

What does this do? Specifically, I have 3 fields out of 20 in 'this' object that I want to pass into the lambda. If I use [&] will it only take the 3 fields I use? And will they be passed by reference or value?

Thanks

Comment: "*If I use `[&]` will it only take the 3 fields I use?*" No, it will take a single field – `this`. "*And will they be passed by reference or value?*" `&` denotes pass-by-ref; if it were `=` it would be pass-by-val. But given that you're only capturing a pointer, there's no difference in this case.

Comment: @ildjarn: "*No, it will take a single field – this.*" No, it won't, but that's only because you can't capture `this` by reference. The compiler should error out when you attempt to use member variables without either implicitly capturing everything by value or explicitly capturing `this`.

Comment: @Nicol : Then does the fact that [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/a07d60a9a53db73a3d14bdbf0a1376e7) works in GCC 4.7.2 and VC++ 2012 imply a bug in said compilers?

Comment: @ildjarn: Actually, strike that. I checked the spec, and there's no language preventing the capture of `this` from a default reference capture. You can't *explicitly* capture it by reference, but apparently you can implicitly do so. That's oddly inconsistent, but it's apparently legal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does this ([&]) do?

It specifies all (implicit) captures are captured by reference. That is, it behaves as if there exists a hidden reference member of the closure object, initialized by the actual captured object.

> I have 3 fields out of 20 in 'this' object that I want to pass into the lambda. If I use [&] will it only take the 3 fields I use?

No, if you only capture members of the `this` object, only the `this` pointer is captured (always by value).

Comment: According to [5.12:15]: `It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities
captured by reference.`, so whether there actually exists a hidden member or not is not specified by the standard.

Comment: @JesseGood: That's why I used the wording "... as if there exists ..."

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is fine (I upvoted). I just wanted to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4):

The capture specification tells the compiler how the different variables are meant to be captured. Using `[&]` means that all variables from the local scope mentioned inside the lambda will be referred to by reference, i.e., they need to stay around as long as the lambda is used. Any changes to these variables will be reflected in the original. You can also use `[=]` which would store copies of the variables being used. If you want to mix the access, you can set up a default and override the way variables are referred to afterwards, e.g., `[=,&foo]` captures all variables referred to by value except for `foo` which captured by reference.

In any case, the lambda object will only store references to or copies of the variables actually being used inside the lambda function or explicitly (by name) mentioned in the capture (thank to jpalecek for pointing out that variables explicitly mentioned are always stored).

In the context mentioned, you mention member variables: these are never captured because they are not in the local scope. What can be captured is `this` but since it is immutable, it is always captured by value. Speaking of immutable: the variables captures by value by default `const`. If you want to change them you need to make the the lambda function `mutable` by mentioning `mutable` between the parameter list and the body of the lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

Using `[&]` as your capture specification in a C++11 lambda simply means that any variable which is referenced inside the lambda will be treated as if it implicitly were specified using `&varname` in the capture specification. The lambda will not capture any unreferenced variable.

Comment: "Additionally, the value this is special, it cannot be captured by reference, only by value. Since you're trying to reference fields of this, you're actually implicitly capturing this. Since you cannot capture this by reference, using [&] will not work. You need to either use [=] or use [this]." This is not based on the standard, and not true with current implementations. In short, capturing `this` when calture-list is `[&]` should be ok.

Comment: @jpalecek: Interesting. That was written based on the documentation on wikipedia (yes yes, wikipedia isn't authoritative). I guess I'm not surprised if compilers allow capturing `this` anyway. I wonder what the spec says.

Comment: @jpalecek: You're right. I checked the spec, and nowhere do I see the prohibition against capturing `this` by-reference. I will delete that section from my answer.

Comment: @jpalecek: In fact, I don't even see anywhere that says `this` is always captured by-value, as you said in your answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: That may be a shortcut on my side, caused by (1) actual implementation in gcc, (2) the fact that it should always behave the same given that `this` is always a rvalue and immutable during the run of the member function (save for the academic discussion about whether running `[&] { return this; }` after the member function it was created in ended is UB or not) and (3) the fact that the standard disallows `&this` in the capture list.

Comment: I've got the impression that the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B) is based on an older proposal for lambdas; for example, "If a closure object containing references to local variables is invoked after the innermost block scope of its creation, the behaviour is undefined." was proposed, but later withdrewn (and not true given the current standard).